# Bash executes a different file from the one prompted, even when providing full path

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, executable

I imagine there's a environment variable or some setting I'm unaware of, but this is driving me nuts.

```
baco:~ # ls -la /root/subversion-1.4.6/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin       
-rwxr-x---  1 root root 57263 Mar 10  2008 /root/subversion-1.4.6/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin
baco:~ # ls -la /usr/local/subversion-1.6.1/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 76125 Apr 20  2009 /usr/local/subversion-1.6.1/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin
```

I have two versions of svnadmin compiled there. If I execute one I get it

```
baco:~ # /usr/local/subversion-1.6.1/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.6.1 (r37116)
   compiled Apr 20 2009, 16:09:36

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository back-end (FS) modules are available:

* fs_base : Module for working with a Berkeley DB repository.
* fs_fs : Module for working with a plain file (FSFS) repository.
```

If I execute the other, with full path, I still get the earlier!

```
baco:~ # /root/subversion-1.4.6/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.6.1 (r37116)
   compiled Apr 20 2009, 16:09:36

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository back-end (FS) modules are available:

* fs_base : Module for working with a Berkeley DB repository.
* fs_fs : Module for working with a plain file (FSFS) repository.
```

If I run svnadmin without path information, I also get the 1.6.1 version (normal, due to $PATH). Via cron I can get the 1.4.6 executed, so this has to be something particular to interactive or login shells.

EDIT:

I know that cron is executing the 1.4.6 because I've run `/root/subversion-1.4.6/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin --version` via cron and I get output from a 1.4.6 version (with the proper compilation date). If I run the 1.6.1 version with full path via cron I do get 1.6.1's output.

Both are binary files:

```
baco:~ # file /root/subversion-1.4.6/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin
/root/subversion-1.4.6/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
baco:~ # file /usr/local/subversion-1.6.1/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin
/usr/local/subversion-1.6.1/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

They are not hard links either

```
baco:~ # stat -c %h /usr/local/subversion-1.6.1/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin
1
baco:~ # stat -c %h /root/subversion-1.4.6/subversion/svnadmin/.libs/svnadmin   
1
```

Comment: In your very first `ls`, why does the 1.4 version of subversion not have world read/execute permissions while 1.6 does?

Comment: because it's inside /root, and it's the default umask for that directory. I fail to see how can this be related, as the test has been performed as root.

Comment: what happens if you `chmod -x` the one you don't want?

Comment: How do you know that bash is executing a different file? That would indeed be surprising. A likely explanation is that `svnadmin` is a script that calls some other executable, and it finds that other executable through `$PATH` or some other setting and not by looking at where it was called through. What does `file …/svnadmin` show? And for that matter, how do you know that cron is executing 1.4.6, and that it's getting it from that location?

Comment: Will update the question.

Comment: A shot in the dark: could it be that the `svnadmin` binary is just a tiny layer of code that loads a shared library to do the actual work (including the version number)?  Then, difference in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` between your interactive session and cron would explain the difference. Indeed, if I run `strings $which svnadmin)`, the version message does not appear in the output, so it's not part of the `svnadmin` binary.

Comment: @Riccardo: BINGO! That was it. Deleting LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the interactive shell makes it behave as expected.

Comment: re-posted comment as answer, then :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `svnadmin` binary is just a layer of code that wraps a
shared library to do the actual work (including the version number).
Indeed, if I run `strings $(which svnadmin)`, the version message does
not appear in the output, so it's not part of the `svnadmin` binary.

So, a difference in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH between your
interactive session and `cron` could explain the difference in
behavior.